# A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces error with LinqPad

Tags: linqpad

I am using linqpad version

I was able to connect to my entity framework model, and i see all the objects fine (connection is fine).  If however, i try to write expression or program i get the following error
"A using namespace directive can only be applied to namespaces; 'System.Data.Entity.Database' is a type not a namespace"

I have added references to system.data.entity.dll and entityframework.dll but i continue to get this error.

Has anyone experienced this? (is this a matter of adding another reference or is this telling me there is an issue in my edmx model project?)

thx

Answer (score 0):

Like the error says, LinqPad only supports using namespaces.  `Database` is a type in the `System.Data.Entity` namespace... you cannot put a type there unless you were setting up an alias.  It's as if you did this in a regular source file:

```cs
using System.Int32; // Not valid, Int32 is a type
using System; // that's fine
using SuperInt = System.Int32; // also fine
```

Check your namespace imports for your query and make sure you're listing only the namespaces (and maybe aliases) but not types.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  You are correct however the answer was to download a more recent beta version.

Answer (score 0):

The resolution was to get a more recent beta from LINQPAD.  Once using version 4.38+ things worked much better.
http://www.linqpad.net/beta.aspx